Defining macros with the same name as standard library functions
Does ISO C impose any restrictions on defining macros with the same name as standard library functions?
For example:
#define feof ...

Does the above have a problem?
If so, how about changing the case:
#define FEOF

If there is a problem, surely the rule (if any) would not be applicable to FEOF as feof and FEOF are two distinct identifiers, or is there something awry about my guesswork?

In a code review, I've been told that defining macros with same name as library functions is not permitted in a strictly conforming program. But I didn't find a SO post about it (yet). I am aware I can do #undef feof before #define feof, but that is not what I am wondering about.

You can define macros with library names, as long as you don't include any library headers...

C23 has a number of cases where there's a macro defining a generic function, and a function prototype with the same name in the same header.

You not only can do #undef feof before redefining it, you should do that.  There is no reason to test whether feof is defined (unless you want to do things differently depending on whether the macro is defined or not); using #undef undefined_macro_name should not trigger a warning or error.  Note that you should define function-like macros (#define feof(fp) …).  Any macros defined by the standard headers to override a function must be function-like macros.  Also, you can call the original function by (feof)(fp) — the function must exist.

C11 §7.1.4 Use of library functions ¶1 is a big mouthful (and I'm not sure why it isn't a bullet list), but it covers a lot of the issues with macros: Any function declared in a header may be additionally implemented as a function-like macro defined in the header, so if a library function is declared explicitly when its header is included, one of the techniques shown below can be used to ensure the declaration is not affected by such a macro. …

Note: the function can already be a macro, e.g. #define fopen fopen64

@LorinczyZsigmond: The C standard requires macros for functions to be defined as function-like macros, hence #define fopen(file, mode) fopen64(file, mode) would be legitimate, but #define fopen fopen64 is not — according to the standard.  What implementations actually do is another matter, of course, but they should follow the standard rules.

The standards aren't always followed; in this case there's a valid reason for that: the user might want to use a functor: FILE *(*fopenp)(const char *, const char *) = fopen;

FYI (may be useful): macros that begin with an underscore, followed by a lowercase letter are not reserved. Have a look: 1, 2.

@pmor Sigh, a long time I have stayed under that false impression. Thank you, I would no longer frown at people's macros in code reviews. :)


Does ISO C impose any restrictions on defining macros with the same name as standard library functions?

Yes, from https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3 :

Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its associated subclause, and optionally declares or defines identifiers listed in its associated future library directions subclause and identifiers which are always reserved either for any use or for use as file scope identifiers.
....
Each macro name in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) is reserved for use as specified if any of its associated headers is included; unless explicitly stated otherwise (see 7.1.4).
...
Each identifier with file scope listed in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) is reserved for use as a macro name and as an identifier with file scope in the same name space if any of its associated headers is included.
2 No other identifiers are reserved. If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.
3 If the program removes (with #undef) any macro definition of an identifier in the first group listed above, the behavior is undefined.

Identifier feof is listed as file scope identifier inside subclouse stdio.h.
Defining feof is undefined behavior if stdio.h is included.
FEOF is not listed, it is not a problem.

Caveat: IANALL [I am not a language lawyer] ...
While it is true that specifying a macro that has the same name as a [standard] function is a technical violation of the spec ...
It does have its uses ... Used in a limited way, it may be fine (spec violation notwithstanding).
Particularly, for debugging [which is what I surmise you want to do this for]. Although there are some good reasons for using a macro, there is an alternative in the second example.
The "trick" is to define the macros for the given functions after doing #include that defines the given functions.
Consider the following code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#if DEBUG
#define feof(_xf) \
    ({ \
        int ret = feof(_xf); \
        int sverr = errno; \
        printf("feof: ret=%d xf=%p errno=(%s) (from %s, line %d)\n", \
            ret,_xf,strerror((ret < 0) ? sverr : 0), \
            __FUNCTION__,__LINE__); \
        if (ret < 0) \
            errno = sverr; \
        ret; \
    })

#define fopen(_file,_mode) \
    ({ \
        FILE *ret = fopen(_file,_mode); \
        int sverr = errno; \
        printf("fopen: ret=%p file='%s' mode='%s' errno=(%s) (from %s, line %d)\n", \
            ret,_file,_mode,strerror((ret == NULL) ? sverr : 0), \
            __FUNCTION__,__LINE__); \
        if (ret == NULL) \
            errno = sverr; \
        ret; \
    })
#endif

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    FILE *xf;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    if (argc > 0)
        xf = fopen(*argv,"r");
    else
        xf = stdin;

    if (xf != NULL) {
        int chr = fgetc(xf);

        if (feof(xf))
            printf("main: got EOF\n");
        else
            printf("main: chr=%d\n",chr);

        if (argc > 0)
            fclose(xf);
    }

    return 0;
}


Here is some sample output:
+ ./feof feof.c
fopen: ret=0x17c3260 file='feof.c' mode='r' errno=(Success) (from main, line 40)
feof: ret=0 xf=0x17c3260 errno=(Success) (from main, line 47)
main: chr=35

+ ./feof sdkfjsldfj
fopen: ret=(nil) file='sdkfjsldfj' mode='r' errno=(No such file or directory) (from main, line 40)

+ ./feof
feof: ret=1 xf=0x7f81e69b6a20 errno=(Success) (from main, line 47)
main: got EOF

+ ./feof /dev/null
fopen: ret=0x1e2c260 file='/dev/null' mode='r' errno=(Success) (from main, line 40)
feof: ret=1 xf=0x1e2c260 errno=(Success) (from main, line 47)
main: got EOF

+ ./feof /dev/zero
fopen: ret=0xa36260 file='/dev/zero' mode='r' errno=(Success) (from main, line 40)
feof: ret=0 xf=0xa36260 errno=(Success) (from main, line 47)
main: chr=0


One of the primary reasons for using a macro is getting the __FUNCTION__ and __LINE__ information.
If you don't care about that so much, you might be able to create a shared library (.so) and use LD_PRELOAD to force "interceptor" functions [what valgrind calls them] on a program that you want to debug.
This is even more effective/necessary if the troublesome code is in a program/library that you don't have source access to. Here's an example for fopen:
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

FILE *
fopen(const char *file,const char *mode)
{

    static FILE *(*real_fopen)(const char *,const char *mode) = NULL;

    if (real_fopen == NULL)
        real_fopen = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"fopen");

    FILE *ret = real_fopen(file,mode);

    int sverr = errno;
    printf("fopen: ret=%p file='%s' mode='%s' errno=(%s) (from %p)\n",
        ret,file,mode,strerror((ret == NULL) ? sverr : 0),
        __builtin_return_address(0));

    if (ret == NULL)
        errno = sverr;

    return ret;
}


UPDATE:
There may be one additional reason to prefer a macro over an interceptor function.
For certain functions the standard library may use a different version of the function. That is, fopen may translate to fopen64.
See my answer: How can I intercept a function from glibc and print the values of its parameters?
I'm not sure of the exact mechanism (weak symbols, weak aliases, etc(?)), but then, one must intercept all the versions/variants.
The stat syscall wrapper can be especially heinous ;-)

Yes, I was defining some stub functions to test some code: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/292320/stub-based-unit-testing

@Harith test/stub/debug is a perfectly fine reason/usage, regardless of whatever[TF] the spec says. On the TV program "The French Chef", Julia Child was flipping some fish in a frying pan and some of it landed on the stove top. She put it back in the pan. She remarked: "When you're alone in the kitchen, who's to know?"

The one who gets the salmonella infection will know.
